# How to bind dynamically create input fields via jquery to wicket page

Tags: jquery, ajax, wicket

I created a static html page to create tree of elements ,and add tree of elements via javascript/JQuery ,now I need to bind the elements to wicket application,

html

```
                <div class="Row" >
                    <div class="Cell"><input type="checkbox"/></div>
                    <div class="Cell" ">col</div>
                    <div class="Cell"><input type="text" /></div>
                </div>
```

javascript
    var aa =
    '' +
    '' +
    'ED' +

$(".add").click(function ()

Create fields dynamically when user clicks, now need to bind data to my wicket app

Comment: Do you have any code to share? Its very very hard to provide help to a question that is only half asked. Sorry if that sounds rude but look at it from the perspective of someone that has never seen your code.

Comment: edited with some code ,basically what I do is I had a wicket wizard and I created static html page with some jquery features ,its a tree of fiiels which refelts a family tree ,now the data I need to send to the server ,

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamically create elements after DOM load you are basically appending these elements to the DOM tree. The reason you cannot bind to them is because the DOM is generally loaded with the page, anything after this is not recognized. You will have to rebind the handler to the element like this.

```
$(document).on("click",".add", function ()
{

});
```

You will also need AJAX to pass the client side data to the server.

```
$(document).on("click",".add", function ()
{
   var theData = $("input[type='text']").val();

   $.ajax({
      url:  "YourPage.html",
      type: "post",
      data: theData
    });
});
```

Bear in mind that the AJAX example provided is only an example.